# Why read from usb char device freezes?

Tags: c, linux, driver

I have usb char device which I managed to bind to /dev/device0 with usb skeleton 2.2 driver (only with few comments to understand it).
Now I have to write user application, which will send and recieve commands as ascii chars.
I am able to send commands with write without problems, but I don't know how to read properly from device.
As I don't know how long the message will be, I tried something like this

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char *c, *ret;
    int fd,err;

    ret = malloc(1);
    char *dev = "/dev/device0";
    fd = open(dev, O_RDWR);
    printf("fd: %d\n", fd);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("fopen() failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    command = "command1";
    write(fd, command, strlen(command));
    while (read(fd, ret,1)!=EOF)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"%c\n",ret);
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

but it doesn't work, it seems to deadlock somehow or get into state very similar to that. I was able to find, that the number of reads is random, usually 3-6 and then the program waits (maybe waiting for data from device, but I'm not sure with this), during last read function wait_event_interruptible() in driver's read() function returns -512 and meanwhile the callback function of penultimate read isn't called.
Why is this happening and how do I find out whether there are any data the device sent?

Comment: [sigh] 'Upon successful completion, read() and pread() shall return a non-negative integer indicating the number of bytes actually read. Otherwise, the functions shall return -1 and set errno to indicate the error'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *ret;
```

Memory is not allocated to your pointer `ret` and you are writing to that location which is UB.Hence you might see a crash. Allocate memory to your pointer.

**Edits:**

Else

If you just want to reach character by character have

```
char ret;
```

**read():**

> read returns the number of characters it read. When it reaches the end
>   of the file, it won't be able to read any more (at all) and it'll
>   return 0, not EOF.

So make the below changes:

```
while (read(fd, ret,1)!= 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"%c\n",ret);
}
```

Comment: Or, since the read is one character at a time (if I remember the parameter order to `read()` correctly), just change it to `char ret;`...

Comment: sorry, I forgot that but that does'nt matter the application doesn't crash, it freezes

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Totally makes sense so added it to my answer

Comment: @Kostrahb When you have undefined behavior in your code anything can happend so please avoid such scenarios then you might not see issue

Comment: @Gopi yes, I'll try. But even when I corrected it, it works like I've said.